# ASP.net: POST not submitting to Request.Form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

When submitting data via GET (Request.QueryString), I am getting the information just fine.  However, using POST, I am not receiving any information at all (Request.Form).

For all intents and purposes, this IS all relevant code. It is mostly markup from the editor.

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
 For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
 -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SGAVotingSite-fd367704-e25a-4611-a728-e1192ddaf955;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SGAVotingSite-fd367704-e25a-4611-a728-e1192ddaf955.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
       ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
       -->
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
       ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
       -->
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
         ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
       -->
      <providers>
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
           If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
           you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
           change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
           of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
     -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Default.aspx Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
    <div style="margin: 12.5% 12.5% 12.5% 12.5%; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 75%; height: 50%; position: static;">

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="5px" Direction="LeftToRight" Height="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%" Wrap="False">
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="72pt" ForeColor="#0066FF" Text="SGA Voting"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="24pt" ForeColor="#FF6600"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username: " Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="24pt"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxUsername" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="18pt"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password: " Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="24pt"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbxPassword" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" TextMode="Password" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="18pt"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" PostBackUrl="./Post.aspx" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="48pt" ForeColor="#0066FF" Height="100px" Width="90%"/>
            <br />
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>

    </div>
        <div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Votes" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [VoteTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Config" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ConfigTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Users" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:HiddenField ID="Directive" runat="server" Value="login" />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Post.aspx Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Post.aspx.cs" Inherits="Post" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VotingYears" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [YearTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SNums" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SNumTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="People" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PeopleTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Positions" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PositionTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Post.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Write("Hello, you have reached POST. <a href='./Default.aspx'>Please leave.</a><br><br><br>");

        NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;

                if (!nvc.HasKeys())
        {
                        Response.Write("Bad request? - ");
                        Response.Write(Request.Form.HasKeys());
                }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Brad! We're glad you're here. Questions on this site should be built for durability, so the next person having a similar problem can use this page as a potential solution. Instead of creating a temporary link to your code, please include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: When I paste the code, part of it is getting cut off, thus the link.

Comment: You've got 179 lines of code there. Are you trying to paste the whole thing? Read the page that I link to in my previous comment about including just the relevant code.

Comment: The code has been moved to the site and it is most certainly *not* the whole thing. Only the relevant code has been included as per logic.